# OpenCV resize returns empty image when aspect ratio is inverted

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm using the OpenCV library in a CUDA C++ environment to resize an image obtained by GPU processing.
A crucial step of the processing involves resampling the image and INVERTING the aspect ratio.

Example problem:

**Resize a 2000 x 500 and transform it into a 500 x 2000 image using CUDA**

This is attempted by the following OpenCV command:

`cv::cuda::resize(d_src,d_dst,cv::Size(500,2000),cv::INTER_CUBIC);`

Where `d_src` and `d_dst` are the proper GpuMats with 2000 x 500 and 500 x 2000 size. 
The maximum permitted resize is a square of either 2000x2000 or 500x500. The function behaves as expected as long as the aspect ratio is not inverted. I have also attempted making the interpolation in two steps, either by expansion and reduction:

- Going from 2000x500 to 2000x2000 to 500x2000.

`cv::cuda::resize(d_src,d_buffer,cv::Size(2000,2000),cv::INTER_CUBIC);`
`cv::cuda::resize(d_buffer,d_dst,cv::Size(500,2000),cv::INTER_CUBIC);`

- Going from 2000x500 to 500x500 to 500x2000.

`cv::cuda::resize(d_src,d_buffer,cv::Size(500,500),cv::INTER_CUBIC);`
`cv::cuda::resize(d_buffer,d_dst,cv::Size(500,2000),cv::INTER_CUBIC);`

Both these approaches fail and are not preferred since they consume a considerable amount of extra GPU memory.

Has anyone experienced a similar problem with this function? Could somebody help me out?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind. This problem can be solved by setting the size parameters to auto:

`cv::cuda::resize(d_src,d_dst,d_dst.size(),0,0,cv::INTER_CUBIC);`